# scroll tip in list control

Tags: winapi, listview, windows-7

In Windows 7, the explorer shows a scroll tip in detailed view like this:
[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd378445.scrolltip%28en-us,VS.85%29.jpg](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd378445.scrolltip%28en-us,VS.85%29.jpg)

This image is taken from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378445%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN page, but there's no information there on how to activate this for a plain list control.

I'd like to get my list controls to do the same, but I can't figure out how to do this.
There's the [`LVN_BEGINSCROLL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774802%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the [`LVN_ENDSCROLL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774816%28VS.85%29.aspx) notification message, but no LVN_SCROLL message which is sent **while** scrolling so I could implement my own scroll tip and updating it while scrolling.

I haven't found any window styles or settings for the list control to activate this feature either.

But since Windows 7 can do this, it must be possible somehow. Anyone got an idea how I could implement/activate this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably subclass the listview and catch `WM_VSCROLL`

A somewhat related [article in MSJ](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1299/c/c1299.aspx) implemented "scroll tips" and deferred scrolling